# Find a leak in Android

Tags: java, android, debugging

I'm trying to find a leak in my app that make the device warms without intensive usage. Is there a way of seeing the number of times a method is called and the CPU time expent for it.

I'm asking that because I don't remember its name now, but for C there is a tool that after compile the app with some special parameters, gives that info

Comment: You seem to be mixing up a number of concepts, but there are some quite informative tools in DDMS.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Profiling with Traceview and dmtracedump. [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html)